# The set of value(s) of a for which $y(t)=t^a$ is a solution to the differential equation $t^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2t\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=0$ for $t>0$ is:

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

The set of value(s) of $a$ for which $y(t)=t^a$ is a solution to the differential equation is:

$$t^2\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-2t\frac{dy}{dx}+2y=0, t>0$$

**a)** $\{1\}$

**b)** $\{1,-1\}$

**c)** $\{1,2\}$

**d)** $\{-1,2\}$

---

I have tried with putiing $y(t)=t^a$.

Hence: $$\frac{dy}{dx}= at^{a-1}\frac{dt}{dx}$$
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=at^{a-1}\frac{d^2t}{dx^2} + a(a-1)t^{a-2}\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^2$$

Putting this in the given equation I cannot solve it this is where I am stuck.

Comment: I find it rather strange that your derivatives on your ODE are w.r.t $x$ instead of w.r.t $t$. With respect to $t$, I get one of the answers you provided.

Comment: which answer? Yes I was also thinking if they have provided the correct question..I dunno

Comment: Which answer do you get if the derivatives are with respect to $t$? You can tell me what you get, and I can tell you if I got the same answer you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not really make sense as it is told. I would expect that the ODE should be:
$$t^2\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}-2t\frac{dy}{dt}+2y=0$$
Making this change gives one of the answers in the choices you were given (I'll let you figure out which one).

---

Well, this is a [Cauchy-Euler equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation), so it makes sense to use the proposed ansatz $y=t^a$. Evaluating the first and second derivatives is easy:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=at^{a-1}$$
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}=a(a-1)t^{a-2}$$
Now substitute this into your ODE, and you should be left with a quadratic equation after factoring out $t^a$. Solving the quadratic should give you the values of $a$ you need.